# RTL8821CU based WiFi USB adapter driver installation

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I just bought a USB WiFi adapter (based on the RTL8821CU chipset), and it upon inserting it into my PC, it didn't work.

It came with a driver cd, so I popped it in and followed the directions to install the driver for GNU/Linux, which was the standard `chmod +x ./install.sh` , and then `./install.sh`.

Well, it starts to do the installation in the terminal, and then it reaches a point where it asks for my root password to "make clean". I give my password, but it doesn't accept it. It says the authentication failed, or `su: authentication failure` `compile make driver error: 1`

Any idea what I should do? Or is there another way to install the needed packages, via Synaptic or something?

EDIT: here is the result of doing `sudo ./install.sh`
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ./install.sh` already?

Comment: Yeah, let me get a ss of the result real quick and I'll update my question with it

Comment: updated. check it out

Comment: Its showing that it didnt find a file right? well, i found the file that its lookinf for, but its in a different folder than where the install.sh is. should I paste the install.sh file into the directory that has the makefile? Or am I supposed to do something with the make file?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to get a different source. The one that came with the dongle itself was wrong, and out of date. I'll update my question with the solution

Comment: *Please do not post text as pictures*, but [edit] your question, copy-paste the text itself and use the `{}` button to format it so the text becomes searchable on search engines.  **0:-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured out what happened: The drivers, make files and `install.sh` files that were provided by the manufacturer were not doing the trick. Here is exactly what I had to do:

1. Clone `brektrou` repository:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/build
   cd ~/build
   git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
   ```
2. Build and install:

   ```
   cd ~/build/rtl8821CU
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Check installed driver:

   ```
   ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8821cu
   ```

**This worked perfectly!**

Comment: Thank you for sharing your own solution! **:-)** You just og an edit and an upvote.  Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1161305/revisions) to improve the readability of your own answers (and questions! **;-)**) in the future...

Comment: Thanks! I'll check them out!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It says I have no wifi adapter. Do you know what other steps I could take to check the instalation?

Comment: My wifi adaptier is not the same, I found the drive in https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=295485  thx.